# Where to store autosave files in AIR App?

Tags: air, autosave

a simple question: I got an Adobe Air app and I need to autosave an opened document. Where can I put an autosave without meeting problems with permitions on writin file?

Answer (score 0):

[File.applicationStorageDirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory)